# Special character to query from latest timestamp sharded table in BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

From
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables:

you can shard tables using a time-based naming approach such as [PREFIX]_YYYYMMDD

This enables me to do:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM `xxx.xxx.xxx_*`
```

and query across all the shards. Is there a special notation that queries only the latest shard? For example say I had:

- xxx_20180726
- xxx_20180801

could I do something along the lines of

```
SELECT count(*) FROM `xxx.xxx.xxx_{{ latest }}`
```

to query xxx_20180801?

SINGLE QUERY INSPIRED BY Mikhail Berlyant:

```
SELECT count(*) as c FROM  `XXX.PREFIX_*` WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX IN (  SELECT
    SUBSTR(MAX(table_id), LENGTH('PREFIX_') + 2)
  FROM
    `XXX.__TABLES_SUMMARY__`
  WHERE
    table_id LIKE 'PREFIX_%')
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you do care about cost (meaning how many tables will be scaned by your query) - the only way to do so is to do in two steps like below

> First query

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT SUBSTR(MAX(table_id), LENGTH('PREFIX') + 1)
FROM `xxx.xxx.__TABLES_SUMMARY__`
WHERE table_id LIKE 'PREFIX%'
```

> Second Query

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM `xxx.xxx.PREFIX_*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX = '<result of first query>'
```

so, if result of first query is `20180801` so, second query will obviously look like below

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM `xxx.xxx.PREFIX_*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX = '20180801'
```

If you don't care about cost but rather need just result - you can easily combine above two queries into one - but - again - remember - even though result will be out of last table - cost will be as you query all table that match `xxx.xxx.PREFIX_*`

Forgot to mention (even though it should be obvious): of course when you have only `COUNT(1)` in your `SELECT` - the cost will be 0(zero) for both options - but in reality - most likely you will have something more valuable than just count(1)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't really see how to easily combine these two queries? How would the result of the first query get used in the WHERE clause of the second?

Comment: in second query in stead of `'<result of first query>'` copy-paste first query wrapped with brackets `(...)` obviously w/o `#standardSQL`

Comment: gotcha. Yeah I missed one little thing with the _TABLE_SUFFIX. I'll update my question to reflect what you helped me with

Comment: BigQuery accepts scripts now. You can set the result of the first query to a variable and then use that variable for the filter in the second query.

Comment: true. with scripting a lot much simpler now :o)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a kind of an old thread but I was surprised why no one offers an answer using Variables.

"Héctor Neri" already mentioned this in the comments but I thought might be better to have an actual answer with a sample code posted.

```sql
#standardSQL
DECLARE SHARD_DATE STRING;
SET SHARD_DATE=(
  SELECT MAX(REPLACE(table_name,'{TABLE}_',''))
  FROM `{PRJ}.{DATASET}.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`
  WHERE table_name LIKE '{TABLE}_20%'
);

SELECT * FROM `{PRJ}.{DATASET}.{TABLE}_*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX = SHARD_DATE
```

Make sure to replace `{PRJ}`, `{DATASET}`, and `{TABLE}` values with your table location.

If you run this on BigQuery Web UI, you will see this message:

`WARNING: Could not compute bytes processed estimate for script.`

But you can see that variable properly reduce the table scan to the latest partition and does not cause any extra cost after running the script.